# Node give Error Unhandled 'error' event

Tags: node.js, unhandled

I was trying to start a node `node file.js`, but received this error:

```
logon fail: 65, sessionID: 2010567
events.js:85
  throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
        ^
Error: Logon fail: 65
```

It seems that a Node process is running on same Port? Can anyone explain how to get around this problem?

Comment: i already tried "killall node" but dont find a process

Comment: I don't think that really is a problem with node already running. I tried the same, it gave me below error:

"Port 3000 is already in use"

Comment: But use from what? I dont see a Node Task and cant kill a node task